# SQL: Compare rows in a same table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to compare rows in a single table
and figure out if "addr" and "zip" under the same id are same or different.

```
  id  |   addr   |   zip
------+----------+----------
  1   |   123    |   0000     
  1   |   123    |   0000    
  1   |   123    |   0001    
  2   |   222    |   1000    
  2   |   221    |   1000
```

So the result should say id *1* has valid addr and invalid zip
id *2* has invalid addr and valid zip.

Any hint will be appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: idea is to verify the functional dependency between id and (addr, zip)...

Comment: Your table has duplicate rows and therefore is not in [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Answer (score 2):

The query...

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT addr), COUNT(DISTINCT zip)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY id
```

...should give the following result on your example data...

> 1, 1, **2**
>   2, **2**, 1

The numbers in **bold** greater than 1 indicate "invalid" items.

If you want to actually filter on this, you can use HAVING clause, for example:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT addr) ADDR_COUNT, COUNT(DISTINCT zip) ZIP_COUNT
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY id
HAVING ADDR_COUNT > 1 OR ZIP_COUNT > 1
```

---

May I suggest that if you don't actually want this kind of "mismatched" data in your database, redesign your data model so duplicates cannot happen in the first place. No duplicates, no mismatches!

Comment: Which is exactly the solution I've come up with. Now the @OP will test your query and finally accept an answer since the standard SQL idiom will work with his Oracle instance and no-one downvoted you (I'm upvoting). I love stackoverflow, lol :D.

Comment: @Anthony For what it's worth, I later noticed your answer and upvoted you, realizing you got there first!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id
       , CASE s.addrcount 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'valid' 
         ELSE 'invalid' END as addrok
       , CASE s.zipcount 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'valid'
         ELSE 'invalid' END as zipok
FROM 
(
  SELECT id
         , count(distinct addr) as addrcount
         , count(distinct zip) as zipcount
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY id
) as s
```

Comment: thanks for the help! Is "s.addrcount" supposed to be this way, or is it count(s.addr)?

Comment: Either way, i'm getting 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
on this area :/

Comment: `Is "s.addrcount" supposed to be this way`: YES

Comment: Do you mean you can't use COUNTs in CASEs directly? Like `… CASE COUNT(DISTINCT addr) WHEN 1 THEN … ELSE … END AS whatever …`?

Comment: @Andriy, No you cannot use aggregate functions in `case .. when` because the aggregate function combines values from multiple rows and `case .. when` is evaluated on a row by row bases. This is why you need the subselect.

Comment: Sorry, sir, but I disagree. Maybe you are confusing this with something else. I really doubt that SQL Server is the only product that allows you to do the following: `SELECT A, CASE COUNT(DISTINCT B) WHEN 1 THEN 'valid' ELSE 'invalid' END AS IsOK FROM (SELECT 1 AS A, 10 AS B UNION ALL SELECT 1, 20 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 15 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 15) s GROUP BY A`. But at least SQL Server *can* do that, which one can verify at [SE DE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

Answer (score 1):

Group by id. Select id, `COUNT(DISTINCT addr)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT zip)` columns.
Filter the rows where the number of distinct address or zips `> 1`.
This will give you the ids with inconsistent duplicate data.

Example:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT addr) nAddr, COUNT(DISTINCT zip) nZip
FROM [mytable]
GROUP BY id
HAVING nAddr > 1 OR nZip > 1
```

Cheers,

Comment: -1 using `[tablename]` is TSQL syntax. And you cannot do a `where` on a aggregate column. That's what's `having` is for. Also you forgot a `distinct`

Comment: You are right about distinct and having. It is fixed. About TSQL, I'm not forced to couple with non standard SQL syntax. If it is not clear that **[my table]** should be replaced by **the actual table name** before, I'm stating it now.